# How to add a custom template page to mezzanine?

Tags: django, templates, django-cms, mezzanine

I've been playing around with mezzanine for a couple days and I've been following this [blog](http://www.rosslaird.com/blog/customizing-mezzanine/), which has been very helpful.

I'm now at the point where I need to make a bunch of pages that need to be based off of a custom template. My custom template is called `content.html`

I've put it in `myProject > myApp/theme folder > templates > pages > content.html` but when I look in the admin console, I don't see content in the drop down menu.

How do I get mezzanine to recognize my `content.html` page as a template?

Answer (score 5):

`content.html` will not automatically appear in your site's drop down menu.

You need to go to the admin site and explicitly declare a page `my content` where you would like `content.html` to appear in your page hierarchy.

For mezzanine to match the two (i.e. template `content.html` and admin page `my content`):

1. Either `my content`'s Title field (in admin site) should be `content`,
2. Or, URL field (in the meta data section of `my content`) should be `content` (if you decide the title will not be `content`),
3. Or, if you want `content.html` to have a custom slug, say `nicecontent`, then fill URL field with `nicecontent` and add to `url.py` a pattern for `content.html` with a matching slug, so:

   ```
   url("^nicecontent/$", direct_to_template, {"template": "path/to/content.html"}, name="name_for_content").
   ```

Answer (score 3):

There's a method Mezzanine uses for looking up template names, from the broadest ("page.html", which all other templates also extend), to templates named for their content types (richtextpage.html, gallery.html, etc), down to the most granular level, which is templates matching the url/slug of individual pages.

This is all covered in the documentation:

http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/content-architecture.html#page-templates

It sounds like you might be looking for "page.html", but it's not clear from your question.

Comment: Stale link: https://mezzanine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content-architecture.html#page-templates