# Django Mezzanine - how to have a custom template per page?

Tags: python, django, content-management-system, mezzanine

Here is the documentation: (its not that clear to me).
http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/content-architecture.html#page-templates

Here is a question answered by dollydagr: 
[How to add a custom template page to mezzanine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16841690/how-to-add-a-custom-template-page-to-mezzanine)

The 3rd method he/she offers makes sense but I would like the url slug magic to work instead of playing with `urls.py`.

If I create a new Mezzanine project and an app called `theme`. 
Inside the `theme` folder I can create a `templates` directory with a `base.html` and a `index.html`.

If I now go to admin and create a new rich text page called `blue`.
What do I have to do to get a `blue.html` template picked up? (assuming I currently only have `base.html` and `index.html` and nothing else).

I've tried a number of combinations to no success.

Update (It works!): Here are the minimum steps to get a custom template for a page working.

```
sudo pip install mezzanine
mezzanine-project myproject
cd myproject/
python manage.py createdb
python manage.py startapp theme
> Add the theme app to your installed apps in settings.py
mkdir theme/templates
mkdir theme/templates/pages
nano theme/templates/pages/blue.html
> Add text: This is the blue page
python manage.py runserver
> Go to admin (http://127.0.0.1/admin) and add top level page titled blue.
> Browse to http://127.0.0.1/blue
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create template with the filename `theme/templates/pages/blue.html` and it will be used for page with the `blue` slug.

Comment: the blue template won't automatically come out.