# Mezzanine Static files not serving from STATIC_ROOT

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, mezzanine

I am new to Mezzanine and not an expert in Django. I am trying to make changes in the default Mezzanine theme. I am doing these steps to override default Mezzanine theme,

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

A new static folder is created which stores all the static files across the project in this folder (STATIC_ROOT). This includes Mezzanine default static files as well from ***virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mezzanine/core/static/***

Then I run

```
python manage.py collecttemplates
```

A new templates folder is created which stores all the templates across the project in this folder.

Now when I make changes in files from /templates directory I get to see those changes in development server.

but when I make changes in /static directory files I do not see those changes in development server.

to make changes to css files I have to go to 
***virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mezzanine/core/static/*** path and then only I can see the changes in development server.

I want to know what am I doing wrong. I do not want to make changes in mezzanine css files, I want to overwrite them form static_root.

Comment: Is your browser caching the css or js files that you are editing in the static folder

Comment: You should also not edit the files in the /static directory because they will get overwritten each time you use the collectstatic command

Comment: @KevinL. No I tried reseting cache

Comment: @KevinL. what is the best way in such case ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mezzanine and in django sites in general, you should not edit files in the `/static` folder directly since these will be overwritten each time you use the `collectstatic` command.

Each of the templates Mezzanine provides can be found in the templates directory of each Django app that Mezzanine is comprised of. E.g the base template in mezzanine/core/templates/base.html.

To edit the templates you’d like to modify, copy them into your project’s templates directory and modify them there. You can also use the `collecttemplates` command to copy templates over automatically. Run `python manage.py collecttemplates --help` for more info.

The mezzanine template lookup system is described [here](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/content-architecture.html#page-templates). This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16841690/how-to-add-a-custom-template-page-to-mezzanine) may also be useful

Comment: Stale link: https://mezzanine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content-architecture.html#page-templates

Answer (score 0):

OKay, After some research I realized, This is not the way to overwrite templates. You want to copy static folder from Mezzanine package and paste it in an app where you want to use it, then edit that copied files. This is written in documentation for mezzanine, I missed that part.